# Extracting form data into a device using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I Need a little help with the task, as I am using react and node.js for the first time, in here I want the user to browse a path from then fill the form and submit it. After submitting the form should be saved inside a choosen path as. So far I have created a form but is there anyway to set just a path of folder so that I can save the data in that path

This is my client side code

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
    import  './styles/main.scss';
    function DataExtractor() {
      const updateList= function(){
        var input = document.getElementById('selectFile');
        var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
        output.innerHTML = '<span>'
        for(var i = 0; i<input.files.length;++i){
          output.innerHTML += '<span>' + input.files.item(i).name + '</span>';
        }
        output.innerHTML += '</span>';
      }
     return (
    <>
      <div id="container">
        <div className='contact-info'>       
        </div>
        <form>
        <h1>
        Tread Data Extractor
      </h1>
          <div className='col'>
          <div className='form-group'>
            <tr>
            <label>Set Output Path:</label></tr>
             <tr><div id='fileList'><input type="text" placeholder='Set Output Path'/></div>
             </tr>
            <tr>
            <label>Select Data Source:</label></tr>
            <tr>
            <Form.Select className='SelectOption' size="lg">
            <option>Select Data Source</option>
            <option>Source 2</option>
            <option>Source 3</option>
          </Form.Select></tr>
            <tr>
            <label>Enter Company Name(Optional):</label></tr>
            <tr>
            <input type="text" placeholder='Enter Company Name'/></tr>
            <tr>
            <label>Enter HS Code(Optional):</label></tr>
            <tr>
            <input type="text" placeholder='Enter Company Name'/></tr>
          </div>
          <div>
          <div>
            <input type="file" style={{color:"transparent"}} onChange={updateList} id="selectFile" />
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <button className='btn-2' type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
     );
export default DataExtractor;
```

I also have a server.js in main

Answer (score 0):

First:Put your select file
Second:Set your your save_path as a params
Third:Send file and save_path to server.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please ?because I don't need to upload the folder or file but the user could choose a path to save a form data after submitting